# How to fetch two different type of user in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which i have four columns

1. id
2. user_type
3. user_role
4. org_id

Now if the `user_type` is 1 (i.e individual) then the `user_role` and `org_id` will be null,
but if the `user_type` is 2 (i.e organisation) then it will have `org_id` (id of the organisation) and `user_role` (his role in the organisation).

There are three type of role in an organisation

1. admin (only one person could be the admin).
2. finance secrearty (could be more than one).
3. approvers (also could be more than one).

What I want
I want to fetch only one person (probably admin of the organisation) if the `user_type` is 2 from each organisation and all the users having `user_type` 1.

My table

```
-------------------------------------
| tbl_user                           |  
-------------------------------------
| id | user_Type | user_role | org_id|
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | null      | null  |
| 2  | 2         | 1         | 1     |
| 3  | 2         | 2         | 1     |
| 4  | 2         | 3         | 1     |
| 5  | 2         | 3         | 1     |
| 6  | 1         | null      | null  |
| 7  | 2         | 1         | 2     |
| 8  | 2         | 2         | 2     |
| 9  | 2         | 3         | 2     |
| 10 | 2         | 3         | 2     |
```

Expected result

```
-------------------------------------
| tbl_user                           |  
-------------------------------------
| id | user_Type | user_role | org_id|
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | null      | null  |
| 2  | 2         | 1         | 1     |
| 7  | 2         | 1         | 2     |
| 6  | 1         | null      | null  |
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Why isn't `ID=6` in the expected result?

Comment: @sagi sorry i forgot to include that.

Comment: @jarlh sorry for that tags removed now

Comment: @rahulsnegi, you're only half done, still one product tag too much. (Keep only one of MySQL and SQL Server.)

Comment: @jarlh now its done. now i can see answers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.user_type = 1 
   OR t.user_role = 1
```

Comment: `t.user_role = 2??` or `t.user_type = 2`

Comment: Yes, it means admin. If you'll look at the data you'll see it will force `user_type` to be 2 . @JibinBalachandran

Comment: *from each organization*??

Comment: @sagi With this even `id` 3 and 8 will come in the result, right?

Comment: Mmmm, no? I don't see why it will selected.. @JibinBalachandran

Comment: @sagi Even that has `user_role=2` and in where clause there's an `OR`

Comment: Oops. Typo, for some reason i saw admin is 2:) @jibinbalachandran

Comment: Even I don't see a reason for downvote. I guess this is the simplest way to achieve the expected output. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the expected result but will also include `ID = 6`

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_user
WHERE (user_Type = 1 AND user_role IS NULL) 
OR (user_Type = 2 AND user_role = 1)
```

You can avoid it to be shown by placing a condition `AND id != 6`, there are no other condition that can avoid it to be returned

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_user
WHERE ((user_Type = 1 AND user_role IS NULL) 
OR (user_Type = 2 AND user_role = 1))
AND id != 6
```

[**Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a75bb/1) you can look at live fiddle

Comment: *from each organization*??

Comment: @GurwinderSingh yeah, one result from organization 1 and one from organization 2

Comment: "There are no other conditions.." . Actually, there are multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: @sagi what i meant is that the data in those two rows is identical

Comment: @Fabio your answer is equally correct as sagi, for that there is a up vote for both but can accept only one as answer.And after seeing the answers "i was like why the hell i was not thinking so simple and wasting my times trying joins". Anyway thanks once again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
from table t1
inner join (
select min(id)
from table
group by org_id
) t2
on (t1.id = t2.id
and t1.user_type = 2)
or t1.user_type = 1;
```

Comment: @Gurwnder singh  : sorry for using both the tags SQL and Mysql (now removed). but thanks for your answer

Comment: @rahulsnegi I have updated the answer. Can you try now?